# Addition with carryover in arrays in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, addition

I want to create simple addition of array with carryover. Also need carryover and result value for display.

Something like this:-

[image: Image showing this task]

e.g `var input = [[0,0,9],[0,9,9]];
 var carryover = [];
var result = [];`

Thanks...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your efforts so far. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, and we cannot help you if you don't show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The two parts you might have been struggling with, I assume would be how you get the carry, and how you get the result..

```
result [diget] = t % 10;
```

The `% 10` part is what is called modulus, here I'm doing a modulus by 10, so that gets you the 10's unit value.

```
carryover [diget] = Math.trunc(t / 10);
```

For the carryover, you just then divide by 10, and then we strip the decimals,.  That's what `Math.trunc` does.

```js
var input = [[0,0,0,9],[0,9,9]];
var carryover = [];
var result = [];

var digetlength = Math.max(input[0].length, input[1].length);

//lets padd inputs to be same size
input[0].unshift(
  ...new Array(digetlength - input[0].length).fill(0));
input[1].unshift(
  ...new Array(digetlength - input[1].length).fill(0));

for (var diget = digetlength - 1; diget >= 0; diget -= 1) {
  var t = input[0][diget] + input[1][diget];
  if (diget < digetlength - 1) 
    t += carryover[diget + 1];
  result [diget] = t % 10;
  carryover [diget] = Math.trunc(t / 10);
}
result.unshift(carryover[0]);

console.log('result: ' + result.join(', '));
console.log('carry:  ' + carryover.join(', '));
```

Comment: It would be good if there could be more than two arrays of differing lengths, for example `104 + 24 + 2048` would be useful. For this case use my answer, otherwise this is excelent!

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff  I did think of that, but was trying to keep the answer short as possible, but I've updated to pad the inputs with 0's, instead of throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1.turn both numbers into array of digits, reverse them.
    2.determine the end index of the for-loop with max length of above 2 arrays.
    3.create the 3rd carryover digits array of zeros (don't forget the extra digit).
    4.Add the respective digits from step1 and step3, 
       as you iterate through each of digits from right to left, 
    4.1 if the sum is greater than 9 then add 1 into next carryover slot.
    5. you should have array of carried over digits when the for-loop is done
         count the number of 1s you have in them.
```

```
function numberOfCarryOperations(num1, num2) {
    const dd1 = [...num1.toString()].reverse()
    const dd2 = [...num2.toString()].reverse()
    const end = Math.max(dd1.length, dd2.length)
    const carry = Array(end+1).fill(0)
    for (let i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        //console.log(i,(Number(dd1[i]?dd1[i]:0)),Number(dd2[i]?dd2[i]:0),carry)
        if (((Number(dd1[i]?dd1[i]:0)) + Number(dd2[i]?dd2[i]:0) + carry[i]) > 9) {
            carry[i+1] = 1
        }
        //console.log('-----',carry)
    }
    //console.log(num1, num2,carry)
    return carry.reduce((sum,curr)=>sum+curr)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is my attempt. It will accept the following as input:

- Any number of input arrays
- The input arrays don't all need to have the same number of items

I've added code comments to explain what goes on, I hope they're informative enough to explain the answer.

```js
const
  input = [
    [0,0,9],
    [0,9,9],
    [1,0,9,9]
  ];
  
function getMaxArrayLength(values) {
  // Determine the number of items in the longest array. Initialize the reduce with 0.
  return values.reduce((maxLength, array) => {
      // Return the largets number between the last largest number and the
      // length of the current array.
      return Math.max(maxLength, array.length);
    }, 0);
}
  
function sumValues(values) {
  const
    // Determine the number of items in the longest array.
    maxLength = getMaxArrayLength(values),
    result = [],
    carry = [];

  // Loop over the length of the longest array. The value of index will be substracted from
  // the length of the input arrays. Therefore it is easier to start at 1 as this will 
  // return a proper array index without needing to correct it.
  for (let index = 1; index <= maxLength; index++) {
    const
      // Get the carryover value from the last sum or 0 in case there is no previous value.
      carryValue = (carry.length === 0) ? 0 : carry[carry.length-1],
      
      // Sum up all the values at the current index of all the input arrays. After summing up
      // all the values, also add the carry over from the last sum.
      sum = values.reduce((sum, array) => { 
        // Determine the index for the current array. Start at the end and substract the 
        // current index. This way the values in the array are processed last to first.
        const 
          arrayIndex = array.length - index;
        // It could be the current array doesn't have as many items as the longest array,
        // when the arrayIndex is less than 0 just return the current result.
        if (arrayIndex < 0) {
          return sum;
        }
        
        // Return the accumulated value plus the value at the current index of the 
        // current source array.
        return sum + array[arrayIndex];
      }, 0) + carryValue;
     
    // The carry over value is the number of times 10 fits into the sum. This should be rounded
    // down so for instance 5/10=.5 becomes 0.
    carry.push(Math.floor(sum / 10));
    // Push the remainder of the sum divided by 10 into the result so 15 % 10 = 5.
    result.push(sum % 10);
  }
  
  // Return the carry over and the result, reverse the arrays before returning them.
  return {
    carryOver: carry.reverse(),
    result: result.reverse()
  };
}

const
  result = sumValues(input);
  

console.log(`Carry over: ${result.carryOver}`);
console.log(`Result: ${result.result}`);
```

Comment: I get that downvotes are a part of StackOverflow and part what makes it work. I’m just left scratching my head as to why this answer was down voted. It works, is documented and I believe it answers the question. A comment would’ve been much appreciated to inform me of what I’m missing.